How to create a special singleton instance of a class in TypeScript or JavaScript
How to create a special singleton instance of a class in TypeScript (or JavaScript) that is not ever returned by the constructor, and yet can be referenced as any other instance of the class?

It took me a while to figure out how to do it, so I'm created this question to answer it myself. There is a similar question with answers that are unsatisfactory. Simplest/cleanest way to implement a singleton in JavaScript . The reason those answers are unsatisfactory is because their constructors treat the first object as special, and same object is returned to the caller who invoked the constructor.
I wanted to create a special instance of the class that is not returned by the constructor, but can be used as a parent of any other object of the same class. In the TypeScript code below, the object stored in universe accomplishes this. The 4 object created towards the end of code show that the code outside the class does not have to treat any of the instances created using new specially; The new operator always returns an instance that is just another instance of the class. The object stored in the attribute universe is created using Object.create() to avoid recursion in the constructor.
Here's the self-contained link to TypeScript Playground with the TS code included, and the JS code generated.
// List of all the SpaceObjects seen so far
let all_objects: SpaceObject[] = [];

class SpaceObject
{
    private _id     : number;
    private _name   : string;
    private _parent : SpaceObject;

    private static _universe: SpaceObject;
    private static counter: number = 0;

    static getNextId(): number { return ++SpaceObject.counter; }

    constructor(name : string, parent ?: SpaceObject)
    {
        this._id      = SpaceObject.getNextId();
        this._name     = name;

        /* If an object doesn't have a parent, the Universe is its parent */
        if (parent === undefined)
            parent = SpaceObject.universe; // invoke the getter `universe()`

        this._parent = parent;

        all_objects.push(this);
    }

    get id() { return this._id; }
    // We don't want others to modify id; not implementing `setter`, or marking
    // the setter private, has same effect
    //private set id(id: uuid) { this._id = id; }
    get name() { return this._name; }
    get parent() { return this._parent; }

    static get universe() : SpaceObject
    {
        if (SpaceObject._universe === undefined)
        {
            // Cannot use the SpaceObject constructor here; will cause infinite
            // recursion.
            SpaceObject._universe = Object.create(SpaceObject.prototype);

            // Special case: universe is its own parent
            SpaceObject._universe._parent = SpaceObject._universe;
            SpaceObject._universe._id = -1;
            SpaceObject._universe._name = 'universe';
        }

        return SpaceObject._universe;
    }
};

let milkyWay : SpaceObject = new SpaceObject('Milky Way');
let sun : SpaceObject = new SpaceObject('Sun', milkyWay);
let earth : SpaceObject = new SpaceObject('Earth', sun);

let andromeda : SpaceObject = new SpaceObject('Andromeda', SpaceObject.universe);

for (let el of all_objects)
    console.log(
        'SpaceObject: {' + el.id + ', ' + el.name + '}, '
        + 'parent: {' + el.parent.id + ', ' + el.parent.name + '}');


Following code is the JavaScript generated by TypeScript Playground for the above TypeScript code.
"use strict";
// List of all the SpaceObjects seen so far
let all_objects = [];
class SpaceObject {
    static getNextId() { return ++SpaceObject.counter; }
    constructor(name, parent) {
        this._id = SpaceObject.getNextId();
        this._name = name;
        /* If an object doesn't have a parent, the Universe is its parent */
        if (parent === undefined)
            parent = SpaceObject.universe;
        this._parent = parent;
        all_objects.push(this);
    }
    get id() { return this._id; }
    // We don't want others to modify id; not implementing `setter`, or marking
    // the setter private, has same effect
    //private set id(id: uuid) { this._id = id; }
    get name() { return this._name; }
    get parent() { return this._parent; }
    static get universe() {
        if (SpaceObject._universe === undefined) {
            // Cannot use the SpaceObject constructor here; will cause infinite
            // recursion.
            SpaceObject._universe = Object.create(SpaceObject.prototype);
            // Special case: universe is its own parent
            SpaceObject._universe._parent = SpaceObject._universe;
            SpaceObject._universe._id = -1;
            SpaceObject._universe._name = 'universe';
        }
        return SpaceObject._universe;
    }
}
SpaceObject.counter = 0;
;
let milkyWay = new SpaceObject('Milky Way');
let sun = new SpaceObject('Sun', milkyWay);
let earth = new SpaceObject('Earth', sun);
let andromeda = new SpaceObject('Andromeda', SpaceObject.universe);
for (let el of all_objects)
    console.log('SpaceObject: {' + el.id + ', ' + el.name + '}, '
        + 'parent: {' + el.parent.id + ', ' + el.parent.name + '}');



